# Matrix transforming - "identity" only for x axis

Tags: matrix, flutter

Transforming - I am trying to only set "identity" for x axis.
The code is Dart, but should be for any language:

This works, but obviously it also include y axis:

```
matrix = Matrix4.identity();
```

I have tried the following:

```
matrix.setColumn(0, math.Vector4(1, 0, 0, 0));
```

Inspired by identity matrix:

```
[x,y,z,w]
--------.
[1,0,0,0]
[0,1,0,0]
[0,0,1,0]
[0,0,0,1]
```